# Windows scripting iconv parameter

Tags: windows, scripting, iconv

I am running Gnu iconv from a .bat file in Windows Vista (Sorry about that!)

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "%1" > "%1"
```

If I call

```
> batch.bat "S:\gutschein_info.php"
```

It executes as

```
> "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 
  "S:\gutschein_info.php"  1> "S:\gutschein_info.php"
```

Then gutschein_info.php is empty. Where does the " 1>" come from? Why is it not working?

Btw: Finally I would like to convert a whole folder:

```
FOR %%i IN (%1*) DO "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 %%i > %%i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iconv does not work if *input* file is the same as the *output* file. So `iconv ... %1 > %1` ist empty but `iconv ... %1 > utf8/%1` works. My script:

```
cd "S:\gutscheine"
S:
mkdir utf8
FOR %%i IN (*) DO "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 %%i > utf8/%%i
C:
```

Answer (score 1):

The "1>" is synonymous with ">".  In both cases, the STDOUT from iconv.exe will be redirected into "%1" or "S:\gutschein_info.php".

Basically, the Windows Command Shell is running the commands in your batch file through an interpreter and trying to turn them into valid commands.  The ">" character is actually a shortcut for "1>", which redirects the STDOUT from the command.

A similar redirect exists for STDERR which uses a 2 instead of a 1.  So, redirecting STDERR would use "2>".  You can even do some fancy footwork and redirect both the STDOUT and STDERR to a file.

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "%1" 1> "%1" 2>&1
```